# Does a tool to view Visio documents on Mac exist?

Tags: mac, microsoft-visio

Is there an open source (or free) application to view (not necessarily edit) MS Vision 2007/2010 documents on a Mac?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[OmniGraffle Professional](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) allows MS Visio imports and exports. However this is not open source or free - but it does have a 14 day free trial version.

Comment: OmniGraffle is the widest used app

Comment: I just downloaded OmniGraffe Professional 5.3.6 and it could not open .vsd file on my mac os x 10.7. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I used the trial version of OmniGraffle to open a .vsd file of a database diagram.  The column names were not in the table boxes. VSD Viewer worked.

Answer (score 5):

As of a few releases ago, [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) (free and open-source) supports not only read, but editing of Visio projects. Pretty sweet. This has been my solution for Visio portability on all my Linux's for some time. I have tested and it works just as well on OSX.

[Read more](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/the-ultimate-quest-of-bringing-visio-support-to-libreoffice) on the added feature.

Comment: Could you update this answer to explain *how* to open a Visio file on OS X? I've looked in the "File type:" selector in the open dialog, but see nothing for .vsd or .vss.

Comment: @Johann just show all file types. File --> Open --> file

Comment: Yes, I can see the file to open it. But when I select it, it opens with Writer.

Comment: @Johann sorry, you'll have to open another question. It seems you are experiencing difficulties unrelated to the OP and/or my answer. Thanks

Comment: I'll answer this here, as I don't believe it warrants a new SU question (since it will be temporary): I was using the "Fresh" build (4.3.0.4) of Libreoffice. The "Still" build (4.2.6.3) works fine. I'll report a bug.

Comment: Oh cool, glad you found an answer. Thanks for reporting back your findings.

Comment: I used LibreDraw to open a .vsd file of a database diagram. The column names were not in the table boxes. VSD Viewer worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can open Visio files on a Mac using [Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com) since it's web-based.  It imports .vsd and .vdx files from Visio.

You can get a read-only view of the Visio files for free; if you want to edit them, then you can use a 14-day free trial or subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

check these 3rd-party, it's not bad but not cheap.

1. [ConceptDraw PRO](http://www.conceptdraw.com/en/products/cd5/overview.php)
2. [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these apps do not really open Visio files nicely... You will find large sections of the drawing moved, or certain images/objects replaced. It becomes very annoying if you are opening up complex technical drawing.

The best way I have found to solve the problem is to use either a VM of a Windows machine running the full version of office or a slightly cleverer way is to download a program called CrossOver. This then allows you to install PC Applications as if the Mac is running windows. I now have Visio 2007 running successfully on the Mac without having to run a full Windows VM Image. Works really nicely.